# Is “Went off” used correctly in these two sentences?

Tags: phrasal-verbs

Is “went off” used correctly in the two sentences bellow?

1) The fire alarm went off.

2) The school bell went off.

And could you give me more examples of things that “go off”?

Comment: Air-raid sirens, burglar alarms, alarm clocks, kitchen timers, bombs, fireworks, weddings, funerals, plays, practical jokes...

Comment: It's worth pointing out that there is a potential, and indeed potentially fatal, ambiguity in the way this can be used eg "Has the ground proximity alarm gone off?"

Comment: In British usage, an alarm "going off" would primarily be understood as "being triggered by the type of event it is monitoring".